# Ember.js how to remove object from array controller without ember data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I am trying to update the arraycontroller model after deleting a record using jquery ajax.I can add a new object using `self.pushObject(data)`, but i cannot remove the object using `self.removeObject(data)`. can someone please help. ("data" is the object that i removed, the server sends it back after removing it in server.)

```
 removeTodo: function(id) {
        var page_id = id;
        self = this;
        Ember.$.ajax({
            url: url+id,

            type: "DELETE"
        }).then(function(data) {
            self.removeObject(data);
        });
    }
```

Comment: What does `data` look like?

Comment: givanse, looks like the json object was different in "data". i followed what kingpin mentioned below and it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data` might have the same properties, but it isn't the object that exists in your array.  See here, both of these objects look exactly alike, but they are different objects, and as such aren't equal.

```
{ foo : 7 } != { foo : 7 }
```

When removing from a collection, if you pass in the object to be removed, that object must exist in the collection.

You would want to first find the object, then remove it from the collection.

```
.then(function(data) {
   var obj = self.findBy('id', id); // assuming the object has a property 'id'
   self.removeObject(obj);
});
```

Comment: Thanks kingpin2k looks like this is working way so far