# How to remove and object from an array in Ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I do not understand why the object is not removed from the array? I tried to implement this solution [Ember.js how to remove object from array controller without ember data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27454228/ember-js-how-to-remove-object-from-array-controller-without-ember-data) but, the object is not removed from the previousParent.

```
changeCauseLinkParentRt(newParent, causeLink) {
  if(!newParent) {
    causeLink.get("parent").then(previousParent => {
      previousParent.get("children").then(children =>{
        var _newParent = children.findBy("order", causeLink.get("order")-1);
        if(!!_newParent) {
            var objRemove = null;
            previousParent.get("children").then(children => {
              objRemove = children.findBy("id", causeLink.get("id"));
              children.removeObject(objRemove);
              children.save();
              causeLink.set("parent", _newParent);
              causeLink.save();
              _newParent.get("children").pushObject(causeLink);
              _newParent.save();
            });
          }
        });
      })
  } else {
    //...
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to provide a JSBin?

Comment: I'm using ember-cli and I am not sure I will be able to create a JSBin. I will give a try.

Comment: If you have an easy solution to create a JSBin from Ember-cli, let me know

Comment: Open the dev tools in your browser (F12 on Chrome).Go on to the sources tab and put a breakpoint at line 3 of your code block. Set up watch expressions to easily observe the values contained in your array by going step-by-step. You might find it pretty fast if you get to understand what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

I found that Ember-Data (or the Firebase adapter) is returning a duplicate of the same record in some cisconstances. So `removeObject()` was deleting once instance the of the duplicate the record with the final result that the remaining other version was persisted back to the backend.